# Make a Java Thread.sleep() return early externally

Tags: java, linux, thread-sleep

I've been having the problem that a Java program I can't change is running a lot slower than necessary as that it waits using a Thread.sleep() at a certain point. I've been looking for some way to make this Thread.sleep() return early using some sort of external program. So far I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026784/java-thread-sleep-implementation) question about the implementation(look at the OpenJVM implementation shown in the accepted answer). So I am now asking myself if I can somehow make the OS(Linux, in my case) get back to the thread an resume it sooner than intended.

Comment: In short: you would be better off rethinking the problem and the solution. Thread scheduling belongs to the OS not the JVM.

Comment: The problem is that you can't change the Java program. That's the problem you should address.

Comment: @efekctive yes, but that is what I am looking for. I just want to know if there is a way to make the OS do that.

Comment: Just my opinion: find another way.